# the meaning of command cmake_policy [cmake]?

Tags: cmake

I am now reading a cmake script, and I am puzzled with the following codes:

```
if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
endif()
```

I understand what CMPOOO3 means as [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#policy%3aCMP0003) has a good documentary. However, I cannot understand the first line `if(COMMAND cmake_policy)`, what does that mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construct `if (COMMAND...)` can be used to check if a function or macro is present. From the manual:

> if(COMMAND command-name)
>
> True if the given name is a command, macro or
>   function that can be invoked.

Typically, this is used to ensure that the CMake script is compatible with older versions of CMake, where the function might not be defined.